# UPDATE-Statement in SQL-API of phonegap fails

Tags: sql, cordova, sql-update

I have following code in my project:

```
transaction.execSql("UPDATE PROFILES SET name='SandroidXXX' WHERE id='2'");
```

I am trying to build it for android but while executing the error occurs: The SQL-Transaction-Callback was null or threw an exception.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762574/phonegap-database-error

Comment: Thank you for response, but this has no effect.

Comment: would it be possible to show more of the code, please? Perhaps the entire routine the execSql is contained in?